# How do I restrict access to certain pages in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wish to lock out access to html page (eg. /manual/manual_A/index.html) 
if a certain condition is not met (eg. HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["key"].toString().Equals("a") ), I wish redirect to specific view (eg. /errorPage/) else continue (eg. /index).
In register Route I add:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ErrorPage",                                             
               "errorPage/",                          
                new { controller = "Home", action = "ErrorPage" } 
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Path",                                             
               "{*_request}",                          
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
            );
```

for read all request.
In controller Home

```
[CustomAuthorize] 
   public ActionResult Index()
   {

   }

protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!condition)
          filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("PageError");
    }
```

OnActionExecuting executes on every request, however, RedirectToAction does not happen. 
Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your redirectToAction and your routing actions do not match, you may want to check that as well (PageError != ErrorPage)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your condition is evaluating to false?  Can you verify this under a debugger?  Also remember that authorization occurs before other action filters.  If your [CustomAuthorize] hooks OnAuthorization, you may actually wish to set the Result from within that filter rather than having a separate action filter do it.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution to my problem. During the day put the code available. Thanks to everyone for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `filterContext.Result` like shown below and then redirect to your error page.

```
filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
RedirectToAction("PageError");
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Why negative vote? I am not telling how to restrict access. My answer is how to stop the action and redirect to some other page.

Comment: Pradeep - Your answer is incorrect.  In MVC, methods like RedirectToAction() and other ActionResult-producing factories don't have side effects like redirecting.  To perform a redirect from within a filter, you set the Result property to an instance of RedirectResult or RedirectToRouteResult as the original poster has done.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.
In Globax.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.MapRoute("PageError", "PageError/", new { controller = "Home", action = "PageError" });
    routes.MapRoute("PathPageStatic", "PathPageStatic/", new { controller = "Home", action = "PathPageStatic" });
    routes.MapRoute("Path", "{*_request}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
}
```

In Controller, I use a Session to memory the condition:

```
public ActionResult PathPageStatic()
{
   if (condition)
   {
     Session["key"] = condition;
     return View("Index");
   }
   else
     return RedirectToRoute("PageError");
}

[UserAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   string patternStaticFile = @"\.*.(htm|html)";
   if (Regex.IsMatch(HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, patternStaticFile))
   {
      string pathFile = HttpContext.Request.Url.LocalPath;
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathFile))
         return new FilePathResult(pathFile, MimeType(pathFile));
      else return null;
   }
   else
      return View();
}

public ActionResult PageError()
{
   return View("PageError");
}
```

In AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["key"] == null)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/PageError", true);
}
```